# How to insert a T-SQL code after a CASE expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a T-SQL code after case in SQL Server. Here is an example:

```
    case count(code)
    WHEN 0 THEN 
    insert into a(c,v,h) values(f,g,h)
    WHEN 1 THEN 
    .
    .
    .
    WHEN 2 THEN 
    .
    .
    .

    END 
    from tbl_A
```

Comment: Your attempt at code makes no sense.  Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression**, not a logical flow operator.

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL does not have a `CASE` statement for control flow.  SQL (in general, not just T-SQL) has a `CASE` expression which can be used in queries.

You seem to want conditional logic, which is provided by `if`.  My guess is:

```
if not exists (select 1 from tbl_a)
begin
    insert into a(c, v, h)
        values(f, g, h) ;
end;
else . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite your logic as:

```
INSERT INTO a (c, v, h)
SELECT
    CASE COUNT(code) WHEN 0 THEN 'f'
                     WHEN 1 THEN 'i'
                     WHEN 2 THEN 'l' END,
    CASE COUNT(code) WHEN 0 THEN 'g'
                     WHEN 1 THEN 'j'
                     WHEN 2 THEN 'm' END,
    CASE COUNT(code) WHEN 0 THEN 'h'
                     WHEN 1 THEN 'k'
                     WHEN 2 THEN 'n' END
FROM tbl_A;
```

Assuming the code count were 0, this would insert the tuple `(f, g, h)` into table `a`.  If the count were instead 1, it would insert `(i, j, k)`, and so on.

Comment: I think you mean `f` instead of `'f'` (and so on) cause those are columns.

Comment: @Sami I didn't mean that actually, because `f` appears inside a `VALUES` tuple, implying that it is a placeholder for some literal value.